# Mixed effects model--nested effects?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I am confused as to how I should model data from the following experiment design:

It is a within participant design so each participant does all conditions:

3 variables

1. Block (home/random)
2. RouteLength (3/4/5/6/7)
3. TestPosition (this depends on the Block and RouteLength).

Explained more:

In the home block, the test positions are always 1
In the random block, the test position vary such that for routelength-3, the test positions can be 1,2 but for  routelength-5, the test positions can be 1,2,3,4 and so on.

I use lme4 in R to model. I am very confused as to how I should model this. I think participant should be my random intercept but I don't know about slopes or any nested effects. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks :)

**Edit:** In the task, participants do 2 block (home/random). Each block has routes of 5 lengths (3/4/5/6/7), and at the end of each route, participants are tested for their memory for certain positions in the route i.e. test position.

[image]

Comment: Could you edit your question to explain what the participants actually do? I have a hard time imagining it from the description.

Comment: @FransRodenburg Done! Let me know if it needs further clarification. Thank you.